ClassCastException in Spark SQL Incremental Load with DBT
I'm encountering a ClassCastException error when running an incremental load using DBT and Spark SQL. The error message indicates an issue with casting in the Spark execution plan:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan

Here is the relevant part of my DBT model configuration and SQL query:
Model Configuration
{% set file_path = env_var('LOC_SILVER') %}

{{ config(
    location_root= file_path,
    unique_key='document_id'
) }}

SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM {{ ref("stg_due_parcels_silver") }} z

{{
    common_dbt_functions.incremental_check(
        update_date_column='insurer_update_date',
        unique_key_column='document_id',
        insertion_date_column='inclusion_date',
        status_column='status',
        apply_full_incremental_logic=true
    )
}}

Staging Model
{% set file_path = env_var('LOC_SILVER') %}

{{ config(
    location_root= file_path,
    unique_key='document_id',
    materialized='ephemeral'
) }}

SELECT DISTINCT
    document_id,
    company_name                AS insurer,
    client_name                 AS name,
    document_number             AS document,
    alt_document_number         AS alt_number,
    parcel_number               AS parcel,
    payment_type                AS payment,
    number_of_parcels           AS total_parcels,
    due_date                    AS due_date,
    payment_date                AS payment_date,
    insurer_update_date         AS insurer_update_date,
    current_timestamp           AS inclusion_date,
    CASE
        WHEN payment_date <> '0001-01-01' THEN 'PAID'
        WHEN CAST(due_date AS DATE) = CAST(current_timestamp AS DATE) THEN 'DUE TODAY'
        WHEN CAST(due_date AS DATE) < CAST(current_timestamp AS DATE) 
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM {{ ref("paid_parcels_silver") }} l WHERE l.document_id = li.document_id) 
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM {{ ref("overdue_parcels_silver") }} l WHERE l.document_id = li.document_id) THEN 'NO INFO'
        ELSE 'DUE'
    END AS status,
    'API' AS source
FROM {{ ref("due_parcels_bronze") }} li


Macro
{% macro incremental_check(update_date_column, unique_key_column, insertion_date_column, status_column, apply_full_incremental_logic=true) %}

{% if is_incremental() %}

WHERE (
    {{ update_date_column }} > (SELECT max({{ update_date_column }}) FROM {{ this }})
    
    {% if apply_full_incremental_logic %}
    OR (
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM {{ this }} t
            WHERE z.{{ unique_key_column }} = t.{{ unique_key_column }}
                AND t.{{ update_date_column }} = (
                    SELECT MAX(tt.{{ update_date_column }})
                    FROM {{ this }} tt
                    WHERE tt.{{ unique_key_column }} = t.{{ unique_key_column }}
                )
                AND t.{{ insertion_date_column }} = (
                    SELECT MAX(tt.{{ insertion_date_column }})
                    FROM {{ this }} tt
                    WHERE tt.{{ unique_key_column }} = t.{{ unique_key_column }}
                        AND tt.{{ update_date_column }} = t.{{ update_date_column }}
                )
                AND z.{{ status_column }} <> t.{{ status_column }}
        )
    )
    {% endif %}
)

{% endif %}

{% endmacro %}

The problem seems to arise from the condition AND z.status <> t.status within the incremental_check macro. This condition is intended to identify records where the status has changed, but it appears to be causing a casting issue in Spark SQL. How can I resolve this error to ensure the incremental logic runs correctly in Spark SQL?
The error only occurs when is_incremental() returns true, which suggests that the issue lies within the incremental logic of the macro.
Additional Information:

I'm using Amazon EMR with Hive and Spark SQL.
The transformation involves checking for updates and changes in the status column.
The full error message indicates a casting issue within the Spark execution plan.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Removing the z.status Column:
I tried removing the z.status column from the comparison and ran the query using a simple string comparison with t.status. This resulted in the same error.
Casting Both Columns:
I attempted to explicitly cast both z.status and t.status to the same data type (e.g., VARCHAR). Despite this, the error persisted.
Testing with a Static Value:
I replaced the dynamic t.status comparison with a static string value (e.g., 'PAID') to see if it was an issue with the data in the column. This also did not fix the issue.
